# electron-builder failing to generate .nupkg

Tags: electron-builder

I went to do a fresh update server deployment of an application (via -full.nupkg) the other day and was surprised to see that the file does not exist in my dist folder.  I've run through and rebuilt on Windows, but I'm only getting the .exe and unpacked folder versions.

I can't recall when I last did a full build with .nupkg deployment, it may have been a few months.  I've tried rolling back any changes that I could think of that are related (other than electron-builder itself, which I can't roll back any further as it has a critical bug fix in it for us for one of our platforms).

My next thought was a bug in electron-builder or that they removed that feature.  However, I don't see any current bugs about it, and the documentation I've run across (while being a bit vague) at least seems to suggest that it's still available.

I did see some references to an "electron-builder-squirrel-windows" module as a recommendation too, but I can't actually find that module.  Is that what I need/what broke?  If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set [target](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#WinBuildOptions-target) to `squirrel`. To use Squirrel.Windows please install electron-builder-squirrel-windows dependency.

Comment: Unknown as to why the dependency wouldn't install the first couple of times, it finally worked on the third try!  I guess with npm the rule is to just keep trying until it works.  Also appears I totally missed the Squirrel to NSIS change.  Thanks!

Comment: how do i set the target?